# Bag has 30 reds, yellows, and greens - How many combos of 10 have at most 3 yellow?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

I've solved this by calculating the sum of combinations with 0 yellows, 1 yellow, 2 yellows, and 3 yellows.

$C(3+7-1,7) + C(3+8-1,8) + C(3+9-1,9) + C(3+10-1,10) = 36 + 45 + 55 + 66$

$= 202$

Is this the correct approach?  I feel like I might need to multiply each combination by the combination of the remaining possibilities, but I'm not positive.

Comment: I presume that all objects of the same color are identical ?

Comment: @trueblueanil Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Actually, if you want to make it into $4$ cases, with $0,1,2,3$ yellow, here you can simply count $11+10+9+8 = 38,$ but stars and bars  is a more general (and thus more useful) approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply stars and bars assuming no constraints at first, and  subtract those combos that have more than $3$ yellow (by pre-selecting $4$ yellow, and selecting the balance $6$ from any color)

thus $\binom{10+3-1}{3-1} - \binom{6+3-1}{3-1}$

Answer (score 0):

The basic approach used in the OP will work, though the answer by true blue anil is arguably "better."

However, there is a little slip in the use of Stars and Bars. For example, if we choose $3$ yellow, then we must choose the remaining $7$ balls from **two** colours. This can be done in $\binom{2+7-1}{7}$ ways.  The other two terms need to be modified in a similar way.